# Differences between the internal and blender players

Tags: python, game-engine

I have a script that I borrowed from the companion files that came with the book, Game Development With Blender (it's a creative commons script).

It looks like this:

```
#Blender Game Engine 2.55 Simple Camera Look
#Created by Mike Pan: mikepan.com

from bge import logic as G
from bge import render as R
from bge import events

speed = 0.2             # walk speed
sensitivity = 1.0       # mouse sensitivity

owner = G.getCurrentController().owner

# center mouse on first frame, create temp variables
if "oldX" not in owner:
    G.mouse.position = (0.5,0.5)
    owner["oldX"] = 0.0
    owner["oldY"] = 0.0

else:
    # round() is a hack to work around the floating mouse bug
    x= round(0.5 - G.mouse.position[0], 2)
    y = round(0.5 - G.mouse.position[1],2)

    x *= sensitivity
    y *= sensitivity

    # Smooth movement
    owner['oldX'] = (owner['oldX']*0.9 + x*0.1)
    owner['oldY'] = (owner['oldY']*0.9 + y*0.1)
    x = owner['oldX']
    y = owner['oldY']

    # set the values
    owner.applyRotation([0, 0, x], False)
    owner.applyRotation([y, 0, 0], True)

    # Center mouse in game window
    G.mouse.position = (0.5,0.5)
```

Inside blender it works just fine, but when using the blender player stand alone, the mouse has to be moved a lot more than normal and the whole thing is a lot less smooth.  What would cause this to happen, and yow can it be fixed?

Comment: In my case both embedded and standalone players work the same. I use 2.73, with the script controller and Always sensor with "Activate TRUE level triggering" on in camera.

Comment: Me too.  I wonder if it has anything to do with my dual monitor set up.  I'll try unplugging one.

Comment: it is not your monitor, and the script is fine, something is wrong with your blender, reinstall it or try the same thing you did with just 1 object and a plane in a new mix file, the blend could also be damaged